# Use API JSON to display a URL for an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I am completely new to all of this so please forgive any issues with how I'm describing and name things.  I have an HTML page where the user enters a portion of a URL string in order to launch a new window with the complete URL string.  I'd rather just lookup the portion of the URL using an API to create a JSON file and find it automatically.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this without user intervention?

HTML (contains text box and button to launch a new window, which I would like to bypass this altogether)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
     <title>Cast Challonge</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#button').click(function(e) {  
         var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
         window.open(("http://challonge.com/"+inputvalue+"/module?theme=5928&selected-round- 
filter=2&show_final_results=0&multiplier=2&show_tournament_name=1&scale_to_fit=1"),"Tournament 
 Display","width=1280,height=720,resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, 
 directories=no");

     });
 });
 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>

        <input type="text" value="" id="input"> 
        <button type="button" id="button">Submit Tournament ID</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My sample API call is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "tournament": {
      "id": 9838153,
      "name": "2021/05/22 Saturday Night 8-Ball",
      "url": "BnkSat0522",
      "description": "",
      "tournament_type": "double elimination",
      "started_at": "2021-05-23T07:01:41.429+07:00",
      "completed_at": "2021-05-23T12:54:30.331+07:00",
      "require_score_agreement": false,
      "notify_users_when_matches_open": true,
      "created_at": "2021-05-23T03:41:49.015+07:00",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-23T12:54:30.580+07:00",
      "state": "complete",
      "open_signup": false,
      "notify_users_when_the_tournament_ends": true,
      "progress_meter": 100,
      "quick_advance": false,
      "hold_third_place_match": false,
      "pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
      "pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
      "pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
      "pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
      "pts_for_bye": "1.0",
      "swiss_rounds": 0,
      "private": false,
      "ranked_by": "match wins",
      "show_rounds": true,
      "hide_forum": false,
      "sequential_pairings": false,
      "accept_attachments": false,
      "rr_pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
      "rr_pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
      "rr_pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
      "rr_pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
      "created_by_api": false,
      "credit_capped": false,
      "category": null,
      "hide_seeds": false,
      "prediction_method": 0,
      "predictions_opened_at": null,
      "anonymous_voting": false,
      "max_predictions_per_user": 1,
      "signup_cap": null,
      "game_id": 773,
      "participants_count": 24,
      "group_stages_enabled": false,
      "allow_participant_match_reporting": false,
      "teams": false,
      "check_in_duration": null,
      "start_at": null,
      "started_checking_in_at": null,
      "tie_breaks": [
        "match wins vs tied",
        "game wins",
        "points scored"
      ],
      "locked_at": null,
      "event_id": null,
      "public_predictions_before_start_time": false,
      "ranked": false,
      "grand_finals_modifier": null,
      "predict_the_losers_bracket": false,
      "spam": null,
      "ham": null,
      "rr_iterations": 1,
      "tournament_registration_id": null,
      "donation_contest_enabled": null,
      "mandatory_donation": null,
      "non_elimination_tournament_data": {
        "participants_per_match": ""
      },
      "auto_assign_stations": null,
      "only_start_matches_with_stations": null,
      "registration_fee": "0.0",
      "registration_type": "free",
      "split_participants": false,
      "allowed_regions": [
        
      ],
      "show_participant_country": null,
      "program_id": null,
      "program_classification_ids_allowed": null,
      "team_size_range": null,
      "toxic": null,
      "description_source": "",
      "subdomain": null,
      "full_challonge_url": "https://challonge.com/BnkSat0522",
      "live_image_url": "https://challonge.com/BnkSat0522.svg",
      "sign_up_url": null,
      "review_before_finalizing": true,
      "accepting_predictions": false,
      "participants_locked": true,
      "game_name": "8-ball",
      "participants_swappable": false,
      "team_convertable": false,
      "group_stages_were_started": false
    }
  },
  {
    "tournament": {
      "id": 9845539,
      "name": "2021/05/24 Monday Night 10-Ball",
      "url": "20210524",
      "description": "",
      "tournament_type": "double elimination",
      "started_at": "2021-05-25T06:34:46.053+07:00",
      "completed_at": "2021-05-25T10:54:03.406+07:00",
      "require_score_agreement": false,
      "notify_users_when_matches_open": true,
      "created_at": "2021-05-25T04:01:56.922+07:00",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-25T10:54:03.589+07:00",
      "state": "complete",
      "open_signup": false,
      "notify_users_when_the_tournament_ends": true,
      "progress_meter": 100,
      "quick_advance": false,
      "hold_third_place_match": false,
      "pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
      "pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
      "pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
      "pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
      "pts_for_bye": "1.0",
      "swiss_rounds": 0,
      "private": false,
      "ranked_by": "match wins",
      "show_rounds": true,
      "hide_forum": false,
      "sequential_pairings": false,
      "accept_attachments": false,
      "rr_pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
      "rr_pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
      "rr_pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
      "rr_pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
      "created_by_api": false,
      "credit_capped": false,
      "category": null,
      "hide_seeds": false,
      "prediction_method": 0,
      "predictions_opened_at": null,
      "anonymous_voting": false,
      "max_predictions_per_user": 1,
      "signup_cap": null,
      "game_id": 6341,
      "participants_count": 22,
      "group_stages_enabled": false,
      "allow_participant_match_reporting": true,
      "teams": false,
      "check_in_duration": null,
      "start_at": null,
      "started_checking_in_at": null,
      "tie_breaks": [
        "match wins vs tied",
        "game wins",
        "points scored"
      ],
      "locked_at": null,
      "event_id": null,
      "public_predictions_before_start_time": false,
      "ranked": false,
      "grand_finals_modifier": null,
      "predict_the_losers_bracket": false,
      "spam": null,
      "ham": null,
      "rr_iterations": 1,
      "tournament_registration_id": null,
      "donation_contest_enabled": null,
      "mandatory_donation": null,
      "non_elimination_tournament_data": {
        "participants_per_match": ""
      },
      "auto_assign_stations": false,
      "only_start_matches_with_stations": false,
      "registration_fee": "0.0",
      "registration_type": "free",
      "split_participants": false,
      "allowed_regions": [
        
      ],
      "show_participant_country": null,
      "program_id": null,
      "program_classification_ids_allowed": null,
      "team_size_range": null,
      "toxic": null,
      "description_source": "",
      "subdomain": null,
      "full_challonge_url": "https://challonge.com/20210524",
      "live_image_url": "https://challonge.com/20210524.svg",
      "sign_up_url": null,
      "review_before_finalizing": true,
      "accepting_predictions": false,
      "participants_locked": true,
      "game_name": "10-Ball",
      "participants_swappable": false,
      "team_convertable": false,
      "group_stages_were_started": false
    }
  },
  {
    "tournament": {
      "id": 9851001,
      "name": "2021/05/26 Wednesday Night 9-Ball",
      "url": "20210526",
      "description": "",
      "tournament_type": "double elimination",
      "started_at": "2021-05-26T20:48:53.085+07:00",
      "completed_at": null,
      "require_score_agreement": false,
      "notify_users_when_matches_open": true,
      "created_at": "2021-05-26T20:46:47.342+07:00",
      "updated_at": "2021-05-26T20:48:53.158+07:00",
      "state": "underway",
      "open_signup": false,
      "notify_users_when_the_tournament_ends": true,
      "progress_meter": 0,
      "quick_advance": false,
      "hold_third_place_match": false,
      "pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
      "pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
      "pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
      "pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
      "pts_for_bye": "1.0",
      "swiss_rounds": 0,
      "private": false,
      "ranked_by": "match wins",
      "show_rounds": true,
      "hide_forum": true,
      "sequential_pairings": false,
      "accept_attachments": false,
      "rr_pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
      "rr_pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
      "rr_pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
      "rr_pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
      "created_by_api": false,
      "credit_capped": false,
      "category": null,
      "hide_seeds": false,
      "prediction_method": 0,
      "predictions_opened_at": null,
      "anonymous_voting": false,
      "max_predictions_per_user": 1,
      "signup_cap": null,
      "game_id": 485,
      "participants_count": 2,
      "group_stages_enabled": false,
      "allow_participant_match_reporting": false,
      "teams": false,
      "check_in_duration": null,
      "start_at": null,
      "started_checking_in_at": null,
      "tie_breaks": [
        "match wins vs tied",
        "game wins",
        "points scored"
      ],
      "locked_at": null,
      "event_id": null,
      "public_predictions_before_start_time": false,
      "ranked": false,
      "grand_finals_modifier": null,
      "predict_the_losers_bracket": false,
      "spam": null,
      "ham": null,
      "rr_iterations": 1,
      "tournament_registration_id": null,
      "donation_contest_enabled": null,
      "mandatory_donation": null,
      "non_elimination_tournament_data": {
        "participants_per_match": ""
      },
      "auto_assign_stations": null,
      "only_start_matches_with_stations": null,
      "registration_fee": "0.0",
      "registration_type": "free",
      "split_participants": false,
      "allowed_regions": [
        
      ],
      "show_participant_country": null,
      "program_id": null,
      "program_classification_ids_allowed": null,
      "team_size_range": null,
      "toxic": null,
      "description_source": "",
      "subdomain": null,
      "full_challonge_url": "https://challonge.com/20210526",
      "live_image_url": "https://challonge.com/20210526.svg",
      "sign_up_url": null,
      "review_before_finalizing": true,
      "accepting_predictions": false,
      "participants_locked": true,
      "game_name": "9-ball",
      "participants_swappable": false,
      "team_convertable": false,
      "group_stages_were_started": false
    }
  }
]
```

Where I am trying to grab a tournament that the state is "underway" and return "url" that can then be used to launch a complete URL as described above.

I've created the following:

```
<?php
 $apikey = 'MyAPIKEY';
 $contents_api = fopen("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json? 
state=all&api_key=$apikey", "r");
 $json = stream_get_contents($contents_api);
 $jsonData = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 print $jsonData[count($jsonData)-1]['tournament']['url'];
 ?>
```

Now I need to figure out how to grab this information and load the page!!!!

Again, I know this is probably not the best way to ask however, any guidance pointing me in the correct direction would be very helpful.

Comment: So if you want to bypass the text box and button then how the user will provide the portion of the url?

Comment: jQuery 1.11.0 was released on [November 15th, 2013](https://blog.jquery.com/2013/11/15/jquery-1-11-02-1-0-beta-2-released/)... you might want to use a newer version

Comment: This is a local server, not exposed to the web.  I want to eliminate the step of the user having to enter anything at all.  The chromebook launches the webpage on startup.  Would simply like for the page to open with the tournament that is currently underway as opposed to the user having to enter anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted using:

```
 <?php
 $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $sec = "10";
 $apikey = 'MYAPIKEY';
 $contents_api = fopen("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json?state=all&api_key=$apikey", "r");
 $json = stream_get_contents($contents_api);
 $jsonData = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 //print $jsonData[count($jsonData)-1]['tournament']['url'];
 $inputvalue = $jsonData[count($jsonData)-1]['tournament']['url'];
 $url= "http://challonge.com/$inputvalue/module?selected-round-filter=2&show_final_results=0&multiplier=2&show_tournament_name=1&scale_to_fit=1"
 ?>
 <html>
     <head>
         <script>
     location.replace("<?php echo $url; ?>");
 </script>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec ?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
     </head>
 </html>
```